# Select from drop-down menu and reload page

Tags: php, mysql

I've got a table that populates data from a MYSQL database and populates a drop-down menu from the same database.  I have the drop down menu and table just fine, I would like to be able to choose which data I show in the table however.

```
<select name = 'peer-id' method='post' style = 'position: relative'>
        <?php
        while ($content = mysql_fetch_array($peer)) {
            echo "<option value='" . $content['Peer'] . "'>" . $content['Peer'] . "</option>";
        }
        $results = mysql_query("SELECT Destination FROM rate  ");
        ?>
    </select>
```

That's what I have for the select box.  How can I get the choice from that and save that as a variable and refresh the table data?

I need to clarify that this will change that current data

```
 #Data#Data#Data
 #Data#Data#Data
 #Data#Data#Data
```

Then choose drop down choice and I want it to show new data

```
 #Data2#Data2#Data2
 #Data2#Data2#Data2
 #Data2#Data2#Data2
```

So it's going to need to load a new page or refresh some how because it's changing via PHP and not javascript.

Comment: you may use javascript to implement your requirement

Comment: The only problem with Javascript is that I need to restrict my data values, and you cannot pull JS variables to php.

Comment: another choice is using `form`, whenever the value of select changed, you should post the change to backend, and pull data according to the new value of select

Comment: Could you show me example, please?

Comment: http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?148094-php-form-with-drop-down!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think `form` may be better, for example

```
<form id="myform" method="post">
<select name = 'peer-id' style = 'position: relative' onchange="change()">
    <option value="1">12</option>
    <option value="2">15</option>
    <option value="3">16</option>
    <option value="4">18</option>
</select>
</form>

<script>
function change(){
    document.getElementById("myform").submit();
}
</script>
```

In the above code, whenever you change the value of select, it will post to the backend, then according to the posted value, you can do want you want, to get the peer-id in php, you can use the following code

```
$peer-id = $_POST['peer-id'];
```

Hope helps!

Comment: Nice!  How can I get that value as variable to use in php?  It would need to be put into `$peer = mysql_query("SELECT Peer FROM rate Group By Peer Where peer = 'variable'");`

Comment: in php, you can use this: $peer-id = $_POST['peer-id']

Answer (score 6):

apply this code in select tag hope this works

```
<select  onchange="location = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;" style="text-decoration:none;">
 <option value="customers.php"></font></option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

insted of the static options, you can do it like this :) here you get all the options from the database. Just replace it with the static options

```
    $peer = mysql_query("SELECT Peer FROM rate Group By Peer Where peer = 'variable'");
    $result_peer = mysql_query($peer);

            if($result_peer){

                while($row_peer = mysql_fetch_array($result_peer)){

                    echo'<option value='.$row_peer['Peer'].'>'.$row_peer['Peer'].'</option>';

            }
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree in using `form`, and with this you can echo back onto the page with a submit button (code tested):

```
<form id="myForm" method="POST">
   <select name="select" onchange="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>">
   <option value="N">No</option>
   <option value="Y">Yes</option>
   </select>
   <input type="submit" name="formSubmit" value="Submit" >
</form>

<?php

if(isset($_POST['formSubmit']) ){
  $var = $_POST['select'];
  $query = "SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE DesiredField='$var'";
  $result = mysql_query($query)
  or die(mysql_error());

  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    $var2 = $row['FieldName'];
    echo "First field: " . $var2 . "<br>";
    // and so on for what you want to echo out
  }
}
?>
```